# Closing Modal as cshtml page properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, modal-dialog

I'm trying to properly close a modal when if I press the x button.

At first i tried doing this in the main index.cshtml page

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
           @Html.Partial("Create")
     </div>
</div>
```

and when closing the modal in my create page i had this

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
```

And the modal closed properly but this was a popup from the main screen.

Although it technically worked I wanted the screen to be a bit bigger. So I tried doing this in the index.cshtml page.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create new link", "Create")
```

The create screen still has the same design with the inline class of "modal-content" but the close button doesn't seem to work. I wasn't sure if it was because the ActionLink part is treating it as a brand new page since most links i looked online seem to say include the "data-dismiss="modal"" part and everything is fine.

If I do another actionlink back to the main page that completely refreshes the page and that isn't what I want because it refreshes the data that the user currently has. There's dropdown lists, query results and filtering done.

Is there a way to treat a modal page like a cshtml page properly so that I can close it without completely refreshing the entire page? Or am I going about this problem the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Html.ActionLink`, literally just drops a static `a` tag to the page. When you click on that, the entire browser view is changed to the new URL. In this context, "closing the modal" doesn't make sense, because there's no modal. You're just display the response from an action that just happens to be the content from a partial view.

Comment: Huh, interesting. That's what I originally thought but wasn't sure entirely. So having the "partial" part is not changing to a new url but having, a partial view? I mean i guess that makes sense since it's "partial"

Comment: Yeah, it confuses alot of developers new to MVC. For a more in depth look at the relationship between views, layouts and partials, see: http://cpratt.co/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-partial-view-client-side/. TL;DR: partials are only partials if they're used as partials (`Html.Partial` or `return PartialView()`).

Comment: Actually, here's a better link, although the first may still be helpful to you: http://cpratt.co/how-to-change-the-default-asp-net-mvc-themet/#layoutsviewsandpartials